# nestjs: dynamic global module

Tags: typescript, nestjs

The [official nest docs on modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules) explain about global modules and dynamic modules. I'm wondering if it is possible to combine the two patterns?

My use case is the following: I have a dynamic config module:

```
export class ConfigModule {
    static forRoot(baseConfigPath: string): DynamicModule {
        const providers = [{ provide: 'Config', useValue: configFactory(baseConfigPath) }];

        return {
            module: ConfigModule,
            providers,
            exports: providers,
        };
    }
}
```

This enables the config-module to be dependent on the passed in base config path. I can then import the module in the main app module as follows:

```
@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(path.resolve(__dirname, '../config'))],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {}
```

which is kind of nice. However, I do have lots of other modules (child modules of the app module, siblings to the config module), where I also want that same instance of the dynamic config module to be injectable. Would be great if I could mark the dynamic `ConfigModule` somehow as global - or is there another way?

I've already tried making the `ConfigModule` global with `@Global`, but that didn't work - here's a super minimal reduced example repo based on the nest starter created by `nest new`: https://github.com/DeX3/nest-di-playground

Comment: Have you tried making `ConfigModule` global with `@Global`?

Comment: Yes, I did try that and I couldn't make it work. I've updated my question to include a minimal example.

Answer (score 7):

Recently I built something like what you are describing, I got inspiration from [nest/typeorm](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/tree/master/lib)

```js
@Module({})
export class LoggerModule {
  static forRoot(rootNamespace: string): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: LoggerModule,
      imports: [LoggerCoreModule.forRoot(rootNamespace)],
    };
  }
}
```

```js
@Global()
@Module({})
export class LoggerCoreModule {
  static forRoot(rootNamespace: string): DynamicModule {
    const namespaceProvider = {
      provide: LOGGER_ROOT_NAMESPACE,
      useValue: rootNamespace,
    };

    const loggerServiceProvider: Provider = {
      provide: LoggerService,
      useFactory: (namespace) => new LoggerService(namespace).init(),
      inject: [LOGGER_ROOT_NAMESPACE],
    };

    return {
      module: LoggerCoreModule,
      providers: [loggerServiceProvider, namespaceProvider],
      exports: [loggerServiceProvider, namespaceProvider],
    };
  }
}
```

Then, you will have a `LoggerService` in the global scope which was exported from `LoggerCoreModule`. You don't have to export the config you pass but I did it since my noncore module has a `forFeature` static method which needs it(I didn't paste the whole thing I built).

Comment: Can you please share an example for the above implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like @DeX3 has pointed out you can achieve this behavior using the `@Global` module decorator. This is mentioned in the NestJS docs in the section about modules:

https://docs.nestjs.com/modules

You can check out a more in depth/real world example of this in action by taking a look at some of the third party modules that have been built for the NestJS ecoystem like the TypeOrm package:

https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/master/lib/typeorm-core.module.ts

Comment: I'm the author of the question ;)  I tried making the module global, but it doesn't seem to work. I've put together a minimal breaking demo and edited my question.